# Is this a safe solution to Screen Tearing on Freya with Intel i3 Integrated Graphics?

Tags: display, graphics, intel, lenovo

I am currently using elementary OS Freya with my Lenovo G510. It has a 4th generation Intel Core i3, with Intel HD graphics. I was searching for some answers regarding the screen tearing I am experiencing with Freya. I found a solution from this [forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=7511.0) and they provide solution by editing the `/etc/environment` file and insert this line of text `CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling`.

I was wondering if there is no harm on my system if I will tried it? Or is there any other way to solve the tearing issue?

Comment: Got stuck on boot animation, I don't know what to try...

Answer (score 1):

You can always change it back using recovery mode if anything breaks.

So it should be safe